# How do I add an item to a dictionary of type <enum1, enum2>

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, runtime, enumeration

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<Fruits, Colors>();
```

Fruits and Colors are enumerations:

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange
}

public enum Colors
{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Orange
}
```

I'm attempting to build this dictionary from a plain text file at run time, so I need to do be able to do something like this:

```
private addFruit( string fruit, string color )
{
    myDictionary.Add( Fruits[fruit], Colors[color] );
}
```

That doesn't work obviously but neither do any of these:

```
myDictionary.Add( fruit, color );
myDictionary.Add( new KeyValuePair<Fruits, Colors>( fruit, color ) );
myDictionary.Add( new KeyValuePair<Fruits, Colors>( Fruits[fruit], Colors[color] ) );
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the string values into the enum values using [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
private addFruit( string fruit, string color )
{
    Fruits parsedFruit = (Fruits) Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), fruit);
    Colors parsedColor = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), color);
    myDictionary.Add(parsedFruit, parsedColor);
}
```

This *will* throw an error if the string value does not match any of the enum values (i.e. it is `null`, empty or a string that isn't in the enum).

In .Net 4.5, there is a [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method that may be more appropriate than just `Parse`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need something more like;

```
 myDictionary.Add(Fruits.Apple, Colors.Red);
```

If you have strings like "Apple" and "Red" and want to achieve the same you can use `Enum.Parse` like so;

```
 myDictionary.Add(Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), fruit), Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), color));
```

This of course has the potential to throw so in reality it would probably be better to use `Enum.TryParse` outside of the `Add` call then after the input strings are validated do the actual call to `Add`.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I'm trying to build the dictionary dynamically. i.e., I need to get to Fruits.Apple from the string "apple".

Comment: @davidkennedy85 I'll edit with the necessary change. As shown in the other answer you can use `Enum.Parse`. The issue you're running into is not with the dictionary but more with comparing strings to your enum.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the string value into a Fruit/Color value.

You can accomplish this with [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or even better in .NET Framework 4+ [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Make sure you cast your result when using Enum.Parse, as it will return an Object.

```
var stringValue = "Apple";
(Fruit)Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruit), stringValue);
```

I have in the past created a generic extension method on `string` to accomplish enum parsing in a more friendly manner.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(this string toParse, out TEnum output)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        return Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(toParse, out output);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Enum.Parse` takes a `Type` as well as a `string`. Without it, there is no way to tell which enum type it is trying to parse.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you.